# paypal SoapClient not working

Tags: php, paypal, soap-client, paypal-soap

I am using PHP's SoapClient class to connect to paypal.  I have a number of problems:

1. The paramaters I pass to the soap call are `array('ReturnAllCurrencies'=>0, 'Version'=>'63.0')` but as you can see in the request below, `63.0` is put in `<param1>` whatever that is.  I don't even see ReturnAllCurrencies in the request.

In this request I am performing a `GetBalance` command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <ns1:RequesterCredentials>
                  <ns2:Credentials>
                        <ns2:Username>xxxx</ns2:Username>
                        <ns2:Password>xxx</ns2:Password>
                        <ns2:Signature>xxx</ns2:Signature>
                  </ns2:Credentials>
            </ns1:RequesterCredentials>
      </SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:GetBalanceReq/>
            <param1>63.0</param1>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I found the request above via SoapClient::__getLastRequest().  It doesn't exacly look like the example on the paypal website. What's with the `GetBalanceReq` tag?  Why does it have the *Req suffix?

2.When using the production server and wsdl files, I get a php error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
>   Couldn't load from
>   'https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl&#039;
>   : Start tag expected, '<'
>   not found

Furthermore if I try to visit the production certificate url in FireFox (https://api.paypal.com/2.0/) I get a ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert

Am I supposed to download the wsdl file and point to a local version in the first argument of SoapClient::__construct or am I simple supposed to point to the paypal hosted copy?  I originally assumed the latter, but now I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "ReturnAllCurrencies" should be a string, not an integer. Also, you need to wrap the GetBalanceRequestType fields inside a GetBalanceRequest element for it to work. For more info regarding the first part of your question along with a working solution, look here:

[simple php SoapClient example for paypal needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105577/simple-php-soapclient-example-for-paypal-needed)

The second part of your question sounds like a temporary issue with the Paypal infrastructure. Best practice is to NOT use a local copy of the WSDL but to turn WSDL caching on and let PHP decide when to refresh it.